# Rewrite url using .htaccess in php with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I convert url(www.mysite.com/attorney_and_legal) to url(www.mysite.com/?cat=attorney_and_legal) using .htaccess rewrite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: thanks timur for a suggestion.